# Spring Boot Application using external properties in my application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

i have a module where i enable actuator restart endpoint in application yaml and add some cloud-stream events. This module is supposed to be implemented in other spring boot applications trough a maven dependency and should register the cloud stream events and enable restarting for that application. The application i try to implement this module in, does regocnize the dependency and the code but it doesn't enable restart endpoint or the cloud stream clients. Does anyone how to solve this issue?

Comment: how have you enabled restart endpoint and added cloud stream event in your module?

Comment: Added spring-boot-actuator and spring-cloud-starter dependencies and in my application.yaml i added this: management.endpoint.restart.enabled: true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: restart

Comment: than i just call restartEndpoint.restart();

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using your module as a dependency for another spring boot project, you need to configure your module again. Please add relavent configuration in your spring boot project's config file.